# Is it possible to configure Apache to host both an ASP.NET Web Service and a PHP Web site?

Tags: php, asp.net, iis

Noob question (because I'm a noob when it comes to Web development). <s>I'm not sure whether I should ask it here or at ServerFault.</s>

I am developing an ASP.NET Web Service and a PHP Web site consuming the Web Service. They are meant to be run on different machines. However, only for development purposes, I need to run both on my machine. I cannot use virtual machines.

I would like to know if it is possible to configure IIS <s>Apache</s> to host both my Web Service and my Web site? Or, do I need to host the PHP site using Apache?

I am using

- IIS 7.5 <s>Apache HTTP Server 2.2</s> (NOTE: I have nothing against Apache. In fact, so far I like it more than IIS, however, I would rather not have two Web server applications installed in the same machine.)
- PHP 5.3.4
- .NET Framework 2.0 <s>3.0 or 3.5 (whichever comes with Visual Studio 2008)</s>
- <s>mod_aspdotnet for Apache 2.2</s>

Comment: i am not sure if you are still looking for the answer, since the edits, but yes it is possible.  The link in my answer is to microsofts setup that will automatically install both IIS, and PHP 5.2 or 5.3 on it.  It used to be a real pain in the butt to set it because of permissions, especially on XP, but since they came out with that its a super easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The best way is to setup apache and IIS on the same machine.  Since it is dev you can just bind Apache to port 8080 or something.  If you need them on separate IPs you need to make sure to change IIS to not bind to all addresses if you want to run both on port 80.

My setup is similar except in dev I bind apache to port 8080 and then on production we run servers with both IIS and Apache where unique IPs have to be binded to by each server.

For running them on binded ports, same ip (dev)
http://blogs.sitepoint.com/2010/07/13/run-apache-iis-same-time-1/

For running them on same machine binded to different IPs on port 80:
http://www.monochrome.co.uk/blog/2006/06/20/running-apache-and-iis-6-together-on-the-same-server

Answer (score 3):

Apache can not host ASP.net websites.  You will need to install IIS, which also works for PHP.  You can get an all-in-one installer from Microsoft here: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9722553

Comment: note that mod_aspdotnet says it is only for ASP.net 1.0.  If you are on a windows box use IIS. There are huge advantages to it, including ASP.net was built specifically to be used on it.

Comment: FWIW, your link goes to a png file that says "Install Now".

Answer (score 1):

Apache does not officially support ASP, however, there are ports like Apache::ASP.
 Please see [the Apache Server FAQ](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/misc/FAQ.html#asp)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Look at [mod_aspdotnet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-aspdotnet/) project.

.NET and PHP files will be triggered by extensions and/or directories. Just set them up correctly in your httpd.conf

However, you will be working with older asp version. If you are on a Windows machine, the best course of action is to set up IIS and PHP.